# Tensorflow: attention decoder

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

In Tensorflow 1.0, the seq2seq API was largely changed, and is no longer compatible with previous seq2seq examples. In particular, I find attention decoders quite a bit more challenging to build: the old `attention_decoder` function has been removed, instead the new API expects the user to provide the `dynamic_rnn_decoder` a couple of different attention functions during training and predicting, which in turn rely on a `prepare_attention` function.

Has anybody got an example of how to build an attention decoder, providing only the inputs and the final encoder state?

Comment: I keep tracking the state of seq2seq library of TF and they claim that apis  with tutorials will be avaiable in v1.1, so just be patient

Comment: There is tf.contrib.legacy_seq2seq.attention_decoder with old attention_decoder or?

Comment: @Cospel yes, it's deprecated though and I'd like to change to a more stable API

Answer (score 0):

This seq2seq with attention model can translate number pronunciations into digits, e.g. "one hundred and twenty seven" -> "127". See if it helps.

https://acv.aixon.co/attention_word_to_number.html